# Handling unseen categorical variables and MaxBins calculation in Spark Multiclass-classification

Tags: scala, apache-spark, random-forest, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

Below is the code I have for a RandomForest multiclass-classification model. I am reading from a CSV file and doing various transformations as seen in the code.

1. I am calculating the max number of categories and then giving it as a parameter to RF. This takes a lot of time! Is there a parameter to set or an easier way to make the model automatically infer the max categories?Since it can go more than 1000 and I cannot omit them.
2. How do I handle unseen labels on new data for prediction since StringIndexer will not work in that case. the code below is just a split of data but I will be introducing new data as well in future

   ```
   // Need to predict 2 classes
   val cols_to_predict=Array("Label1","Label2")

   // ID col
   val omit_cols=Array("Key")

   // reading the csv file
   val data = sqlContext.read
   .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
   .option("header", "true") // Use first line of all files as header
   .option("inferSchema", "true") // Automatically infer data types
   .load("abc.csv")
   .cache()

   // creating a features DF by droppping the labels so that I can run all 
   // the cols through String Indexer
   val features=data.drop("Label1").drop("Label2").drop("Key")

   // Since I do not know my max categories possible, I find it out
   // and use it for maxBins parameter in RF
   val distinct_col_counts=features.columns.map(x => data.select(x).distinct().count ).max

   val transformers: Array[org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage] = features.columns.map(
     cname => new StringIndexer().setInputCol(cname).setOutputCol(s"${cname}_index").fit(features)
   )
   val assembler  = new VectorAssembler()
     .setInputCols(features.columns.map(cname => s"${cname}_index"))
     .setOutputCol("features")

   val labelIndexer2 = new StringIndexer()
     .setInputCol("prog_label2")
     .setOutputCol("Label2")
     .fit(data)

   val labelIndexer1 = new StringIndexer()
     .setInputCol("orig_label1")
     .setOutputCol("Label1")
     .fit(data)

   val rf = new RandomForestClassifier()
     .setLabelCol("Label1")
     .setFeaturesCol("features")
     .setNumTrees(100)
     .setMaxBins(distinct_col_counts.toInt)

   val labelConverter = new IndexToString()
     .setInputCol("prediction")
     .setOutputCol("predictedLabel")
     .setLabels(labelIndexer1.labels)

   // Split into train and test
   val Array(trainingData, testData) = data.randomSplit(Array(0.7, 0.3))
   trainingData.cache()
   testData.cache()

   // Running only for one label for now Label1
   val stages: Array[org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage] =transformers :+ labelIndexer1 :+ assembler :+ rf :+ labelConverter //:+ labelIndexer2

   val pipeline=new Pipeline().setStages(stages)
   val model=pipeline.fit(trainingData)
   val predictions = model.transform(testData)
   ```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it is on one hand too broad, and on other hands cannot fit in the scope of question that can be answered on SO. You can't get code review here. Sorry!

Comment: @eliasah I have a doubt on whether the steps I am taking is correct also. the pipeline that is. That is why I posted the code. Improvements can be a byproduct of the question. Is that acceptable?

Comment: @eliasah Should I break the question in different questions? Since I have doubts on handling unseen labels,maxbins calculation and scalability issues. I just thought putting it together would make it easy for all to answer.

Comment: I suggest you [edit] your question into specifically asking about handling unseen labels, showing as little code as possible to make a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then, when you get your code to work as intended, post the entire thing on [codereview.se] to address the scalability and performance part.

Comment: @Mat'sMug The question title and body has been edited. Code has also been removed which was unnecessary. Thanks for the moderation!