# Making the features of test data same as train data after featureselection in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, feature-selection, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I m working on Scala. I have a big question, ChiSqSelector seems to reduce dimension successfully, but I can't identify what features were reduced what were remained. How can I know what features were reduced?

```
[WrappedArray(a, b, c),(5,[1,2,3],[1,1,1]),(2,[0],[1])]
[WrappedArray(b, d, e),(5,[0,2,4],[1,1,2]),(2,[1],[2])]
[WrappedArray(a, c, d),(5,[0,1,3],[1,1,1]),(2,[0],[1])]
```

PS: when I wanted to make the test data same as feature-selected train data I found that I dont know how to do that in scala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use **MLlib** version of the `ChiSqSelector` you can `selectedFeatures`:

```
mllibModel: org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.ChiSqSelectorModel = ???
val features: Array[Int] = mllib.selectedFeatures
```

Nevertheless when you work with test data it is better to use selector trained on the train dataset and don't bother with manual selection.

```
val testData: RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector] = ???
mllibModel.transform(testData)
```

The same rules apply to **ML** version. You can use `selectedFeatures` to extract array of indices:

```
val mlModel: org.apache.spark.ml.feature.ChiSqSelectorModel = ???
val features: Array[Int] = mlModel.selectedFeatures
```

but it is still better to keep model and reuse on new data:

```
val testData: RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame] = ???
mlModel.transform(testData)
```

If you want a human readable list of features you can analyze column metadata after transformation as shown in [Tagging columns as Categorical in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34070050/1560062)

Comment: Nope, I mean can I use chisqModel.transform(testData) if  test data without label ?

Comment: Check the types in the answer :)